# find $\theta$ for $ 2 \sin^2 (\frac{A-\theta}{2})\leq 1 + d^2 -2d \cos(\theta) $.

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the range of $\theta$ as a function of $A$ and $d$ such that $x \leq y$.

we have $0<\theta<A$ and $0<d<1$ and $\alpha + \theta = A$.

Does anyone have any idea?
[image]

I think the following must be solved:
$$
4 \sin^2 (\frac{A-\theta}{2}) \leq 1 + d^2 -2d \cos(\theta)
$$

Comment: is it an inequality or an equality.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam It is an inequality. It also had a mistake, I modified it.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a Hint**

use

$a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x-y)$

with

$$\cos(y)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: Could not find $\theta$ in a closed-form. :/